# React typescript forwardref with defaultProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ref, react-forwardref

I was trying to use defaultProps in functional component along with forwardRef, but was getting the error (refer screenshot).

I don't want to destructure the props in function params and assign default value. because got a lot of props in my original usecase.
I also tried assigning the default values JSON directly to ComponentA.defaultProps still same result.
[image]
How to resolve this ? Tried surfing but was not able to find any solution.
Also since we are using TS for type check, do we still need prototype JSON ?
#App.tsx

```
import './App.css';
import ComponentA from './components/A/A';
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ComponentA>
        <button>Button I am</button>
      </ComponentA>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

#ComponentA.tsx

```
import React,{forwardRef} from "react"
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

type Props =  {
    children:JSX.Element | JSX.Element[],
    text:string,
    text1?:string,
} 

const ComponentA=(prop:Props)=>{
    return <div>Hey
        {prop.children}
        {prop.text}
        {prop.text1}
    </div>
}
ComponentA.prototype = {
    children:PropTypes.element.isRequired,
    text:PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    text1:PropTypes.string
}

ComponentA.defaultProps={
    text: 'done'
} as Partial<Props>
export default forwardRef<HTMLAllCollection,Props>(ComponentA)
```

Thanks

Comment: can you share the code snippet?

Comment: @YedidyaRashi updated the post with snippet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Brian Vaughn](https://github.com/bvaughn) [commmented](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/16653#issuecomment-557603361) on the issue of [Stateless Component: React.forwardRef make defaultProps invalid](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/16653)

> The function passed to `forwardRef` is not a React component. (React components don't accept a second `ref` param for example.) It's just a function that "renders" (returns) React elements. So it does not support `defaultProps`. We have [tests](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/0bd0c5269f2fe90ff7897ed5ce9146db99126eaf/packages/react/src/__tests__/forwardRef-test.js#L150-L171) that confirm this as expected behavior.
>
> React also logs the following error in the console (as can be seen in your Code [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-field-95pqc) repro):
>
> > Warning: forwardRef render functions do not support propTypes or >defaultProps. Did you accidentally pass a React component?

That is the reason why you can not attach `defaultProps` before passing the `function that "renders"` to the `forwordRef`.

It's also mentioned in the [type definitions of react](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/index.d.ts#L543):

```
// the input of ForwardedRef
interface ForwardRefRenderFunction<T, P = {}> {
    (props: P, ref: ForwardedRef<T>): ReactElement | null;
    displayName?: string | undefined;
    // explicit rejected with `never` required due to
    // https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/36826
    /**
     * defaultProps are not supported on render functions
     */
    defaultProps?: never | undefined;
    /**
     * propTypes are not supported on render functions
     */
    propTypes?: never | undefined;
}
```

In your case just inverse the order of declarations:

```
import "./styles.css";
import { forwardRef } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

type Props = {
  children: JSX.Element | JSX.Element[];
  // NOTE: text is optional since he has default value.
  text?: string;
  text1?: string;
};

const ComponentA = forwardRef<HTMLAllCollection, Props>((prop: Props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      Hey
      {prop.children}
      {prop.text}
      {prop.text1}
    </div>
  );
});

ComponentA.prototype = {
  children: PropTypes.element.isRequired,
  text: PropTypes.string,
  text1: PropTypes.string
};

ComponentA.defaultProps = {
  text: "done"
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <ComponentA>
      <button>Button I am</button>
    </ComponentA>
  );
}
```

[Sandbox Code](https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-ride-iubrrb)

Comment: tried your solution, working fine.
Still I am not able to understand why it behaves diff when we wrap forwardRef while exporting vs using forwardRef while declaring.

Comment: does it clearer now?

Comment: thanks for the detailed info, now able to wrap my head around this.